# Python unicode object must be encoded before hashing

Tags: python, django, hash, encoding

I am trying to hash some random string:

```
key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
salt = hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest()[:5].encode('utf-8')            
activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+email).hexdigest()
```

When I do this it says unicode object must be encoded before hashing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  # lines omitted..
  File <something>, line <digits>, in <module name>
    salt = hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest()[:5].encode('utf-8')            
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Whats wrong in here? I have even encoded key.

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception? Encoding the salt looks like the wrong thing to do here; it is not unicode data that it returns. What type of object is `email`?

Comment: email is user email that I am getting from user model

Comment: are you using python3?

Comment: Yes, so it is a Unicode object, probably.

Comment: yes I am using python3

Comment: yes it might be unicode object. but its not hashing

Comment: @gamer: this is why you always need to include the full traceback; in this case it is the `hashlib.sha1(key)` expression that throws the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` and `email` objects are Unicode values too. You'll have to encode those:

```
key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
salt = hashlib.sha1(key.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()[:5]           
activation_key = hashlib.sha1((salt + email).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
```

I'm not sure why you are first hashing the random salt key here, however; you are limiting the salt value now by taking the first 5 hexadecimal digits, limiting yourself to the letters a-f and numbers 0-9.

Just use a random string without further hashing, but perhaps expand the number of possible characters. Encode them up-front even:

```
salt_bytes = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits).encode('ascii')
salt = bytes([random.choice(salt_bytes) for _ in range(5)])
activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt + email.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
```

Then again, if this is to be an activation key, unless you store the random salt somewhere separate you can never recreate that key from the email address alone. You may as well use 40 random `string.hexdigits` characters to generate that key.

Comment: I am storing the activation key in a model. Thank you for the suggestion I will use 40 random strings..